# Spacing in subscripts

Tags: spacing

Obviously if you put `n{=}1` into a LaTeX document you don't get the proper spacing that you get with `n=1`, **except** that in things like `\sum_{n=1}^\infty` the spacing seems no different from what it would be if you write `\sum_{n{=}1}^\infty`.

But if I recall correctly, in Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* it's not like that; it looks the way it would if you wrote `\sum_{n\,=\,1}^\infty`.

Is there some standard way of having it do that every time by putting something above the `\begin{document}` line? Or if not that, some reasonable non-standard way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX suppresses spaces around binary operation symbols in subscripts and superscripts.

Can you reinstate it? Yes, if you wrap the subscript/superscript in `\text{$...$}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\oldsum\sum % for comparison

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sum}{\DOTSB\spaced@sum}
\NewDocumentCommand{\spaced@sum}{e{_^}}{%
  \sum@\slimits@
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{\text{\m@th $#1$}}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{^{\text{\m@th $#2$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\oldsum\dots\oldsum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
\\
\sum\dots\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're running an older version of LaTeX you may need `\usepackage{xparse}`.

If you replace the main definition with

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\spaced@sum}{e{_^}}{%
  \sum@\slimits@
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{\text{\thickmuskip=3mu \m@th $#1$}}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{^{\text{\thickmuskip=3mu \m@th $#2$}}}%
}
```

you get less space.

[image]

You can abstract the setting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\oldsum\sum % for comparison

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\spaced@operator}{me{_^}}{%
  \csname #1@\endcsname\slimits@
  \IfValueT{#2}{_{\text{\thickmuskip=3mu \m@th $#2$}}}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{^{\text{\thickmuskip=3mu \m@th $#3$}}}%
}
\def\operator@list{%
  coprod,bigvee,bigwedge,biguplus,%
  bigcap,bigcup,prod,sum,bigotimes,%
  bigoplus,bigodot,bigsqcup%
}
\@for\next:=\operator@list\do{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname\next\endcsname{%
    \noexpand\DOTSB\spaced@operator{\next}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand\lim{\spaced@lim{lim}}
\renewcommand\liminf{\spaced@lim{lim\,inf}}
\renewcommand\limsup{\spaced@lim{lim\,sup}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\spaced@lim}{me{_^}}{%
  \qopname\relax m{#1}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{_{\text{\thickmuskip=3mu \m@th $#2$}}}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{^{\text{\thickmuskip=3mu \m@th $#3$}}}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\oldsum\dots\oldsum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
\\
\sum\dots\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
\\
\prod_{a=1}\lim_{n\to\infty}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So this works only with \sum and not with \lim, \max, etc. How would one cause TeX not to suppress spaces around binary operation symbols in subscripts and superscripts?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry, you have to do it for every big operator; the procedure can be abstracted, though. I’ll add some ideas.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I added the “abstraction": the list of big operators comes from `amsmath`.

Comment: This works with `\lim` but not with `\max`. Would just adding that to the list do it?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Just add `\renewcommand\max{\spaced@lim{max}}` and similarly for `\min\sup\inf`